# Reuse Aggregation in Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the query below, does SQL need to calculate `SUM(MY_INDICATOR)` twice (once for each field it is used in) or is it optimized to perform the aggregation only once?

```
SELECT
  ID,
  SUM(MY_INDICATOR) AS MY_SUM,
  SUM(MY_INDICATOR) / COUNT(*) AS MY_RATE
FROM
  SOMETABLE
GROUP BY
  ID
```

Comment: Did you check the execution plans? You can probably track the computer scalar operators to find out.

Comment: It is very unlikely that the DBMS does that calculation twice. There is an optimizer working in the DBMS and this is a case that is very esay top detect and optimize. Anyway, just don't worry. Trust the DBMS to do its best, as this is usually the case.

Comment: Why are you using `SUM(MY_INDICATOR) / COUNT(*)` anyway? This looks like a potentially incorrect (in the presence of nulls) replacement for the built in `AVG` function.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with syntax. You can replace SUM(MY_INDICATOR) with whatever aggregation makes you happy...

Comment: well chances are that it will evaluate it multiple times. most of the time it doesnt make any discernible difference but it is possible to come up with scenarios where it does. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/27/bug-slow-sums-and-averages.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are worried about an optimization that is rather irrelevant.  The expense of an aggregation query is in reading the data and rearranging it so common key values can be processed at the same time.  A simple `sum()` is not a performance issue.

That said, assuming that `my_indicator` is not `NULL`, you can simplify the logic to:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(MY_INDICATOR) AS MY_SUM,
       AVG(MY_INDICATOR * 1.0) AS MY_RATE
FROM SOMETABLE
GROUP BY ID;
```

The `* 1.0` is because SQL Server does integer arithmetic -- to avoid that (even in your version) you want to convert to a number format with decimal places.

I often write this logic as:

```
avg(case when my_indicator = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end)
```

Comment: I don't agree with your analysis. The sum aggregation specifically is not important to the issue. I could replace SUM(MY_INDICATOR) with some extremely expensive aggregation and ask the same question. Syntax is not what I am asking about.

Answer (score -1):

It would have to calculate it twice, you could do something like this so you only had to calculate it once:

```
SELECT ID, MY_SUM, 
       MY_SUM / MY_COUNT AS MY_RATE
FROM ( SELECT ID,
              SUM(MY_INDICATOR) AS MY_SUM,
              COUNT(*) AS MY_COUNT
       FROM  SOMETABLE
       GROUP BY ID
     ) t;
```

Comment: Is there any way to prove this using the execution plan or with a timed trial query?

Comment: Im not sure about execution plan, but for timed trial query, you could, but would have to be a large enough dataset to be show any identifiable difference.  If doing timed would also have to take into account any cashed execution plans/etc as well.